# Energy Balance for a reactor

Tags: energy, temperature

> There's wastewater flowing into the reactor at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$ and the reactor is maintained at $\pu{36 ^\circ C}$. The effluent of the reactor flows into the stripper, which is at $\pu{65 ^\circ C}$. How can you maintain the temperature at $\pu{36 ^\circ C}$ in the left reactor with fresh wastewater flowing in at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$ and stripped wastewater flowing in at $\pu{65 ^\circ C}$?

$$\underset{\mathrm{input}}{\pu{20 ^\circ C}}\ce{->[$Q_i$]} \underset{\mathrm{reactor}}{\pu{36^\circ C}} \ce{<=>[Q_e][Q_r]} \underset{\mathrm{stripper}}{\pu{65 ^\circ C}} \ce{->} \mathrm{output}$$

When I did the mass balance, it's $Q_i = Q_s$. I don't know how you can get the $60\%$ of energy change during inflow using the energy balance.  How do you find that $Q_r = 60\%$ of $Q_i$?

Comment: What is the actual question here? I fail to understand, As an answer to your first question, we get that from the question itself. It is a statement and not something you need to prove.

Comment: Qr is supposed to be 60% of Qi. This is the answer. However, I am trying to figure out how to derive this using energy balance.

Comment: Is this the complete question? Could you share the exact phrasing of the question?

Comment: The question is: how can you maintain the temperature at 36 deg Celsius in the left reactor with fresh wastewater flowing in at 20 deg Celsius and stripped wastewater flowing at 65 deg Celsius?

Comment: Oh, so the question is what is Qr in terms of Qi?